# Django filtering child objects in class-based generic list view

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship, django-class-based-views

Good day for all!

My app used django class-based generic list view. I have two model objects: Books and Publishers that linked via foreign key (code below). I want to use ListView to show publishers with their books, but filter books (get only active books, owned by current user)

Additional info: I don't want to use filter in template if it's possible.
Additional info 2: I can't use filter via define in model class because I need access to request object

code

models.py

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, related_name='books')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

views.py

```
class ListBooksByPublisher(ListView):
    model = Publisher
    template_name = 'list.html'
    context_object_name = 'books'
```

list.html

```
{% for publisher in publishers %}
    {{ publisher.name }}
    {% for book in publisher.books.all %}
        {{ book.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

you need to overwrite the [get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) method on the view to return your custom queryset

For example:

```
class ListBooksByPublisher(ListView):
    ....
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(blablabla))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I use get_queryset to filter Publisher (parent object). But I can't understand how to use it to filter child objects.

Comment: that's a different question :) create another question on SO on how to filter sub child objects

Comment: Thats is exact question I asked. Django filtering *child* objects

Comment: You migth want to check this https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17001 . You are looking to add filters to the related objects

Answer (score 0):

You may write your custom filter, which returns list of books for a publisher.

yourapp/templatetags/my_filters.py:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_books(publisher):
    return publisher.book_set.filter(YOUR_CUSTOM_FILTER)
```

Your template:

```
{% load get_books from my_filters %}
...
{% for publisher in publishers %}
    {{ publisher.name }}
    {% for book in publisher|get_books %}
        {{ book.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Another way is to pass extra data to your view:

```
class ListBooksByPublisher(ListView):
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListBooksByPublisher, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['publishers_with_books'] = your_custom_data_structure
        return context
```

Comment: Just keep one thing in mind: there is nothing wrong with using the function based view if your requirements are too complex for a CBV.

Answer (score -2):

```
#views
class ListBooksByPublisher(ListView):
    model = Publisher
    template_name = 'list.html'
    context_object_name = 'publishers'
#tmp
{% for publisher in publishers %}
    {{ publisher.name }}
    {% for book in publisher.book_set.all %}
        {{ book.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I can't find a filter here, sorry.